# Convert unsigned long to char*, disregard high 0 bytes

Tags: c++, binary, fstream

I have an unsigned long long variable which I want to write to a binary file. However, I need to neglect all leading bytes which are zero.
This means

```
unsigned long long toWrite = 4;
```

should write 0x04 and not 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x04 to the stream.

```
#include <fstream>
int main(){
  std::ofstream out("test.txt", std::ios::binary);
  unsigned long long toWrite = 4;
  out << cutoffZeroBytes(toWrite);
  out.close();
  return 1;
}
```

I was thinking about making `cutoffZeroBytes` a function which returns a `char*`. But if there are zero bytes in the middle (e.g. 0x03 0x00 0xf1), then I think I couldn't write it to the stream, since 0x00 determines the end of an `char` array.
I'm a little clueless here and need some help.

Comment: you can return a char * and a length.   Treating a char * like a string is only a convention, not a requirement.  It's just as valid to treat it as a pointer to an array of char's.  You couldn't use operator<< though.  ostream::write should work fine though.

Comment: also, what output do you expect if the value is actually 0?

Comment: make the minimum to a single byte and the problem of the 0 is solved

Comment: @J3STER yes, but that's not something the question states.

Comment: @xaxxon how do you suggest to convert the number into a char*? because if you have the int 1234, and try to convert it to a char*->["1234"],
that wouldnt work. That would result in -> [49,50,51,52] instead of the desired [4,210]

Comment: @xaxxon do you think unions are an option?

Comment: @J3STER I think sam's answer is reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using write for this aim.
So, just change:

```
out << cutoffZeroBytes(toWrite);
```

to:

```
out.write((char*)&toWrite, sizeof(toWrite));
```

And if you want to cut this number:

```
char* start = (char*)&toWrite;
int pi = sizeof(toWrite);
for (; pi > 0; pi--, start++)
    if (*start)
        break;
out.write(start, pi);
```

Comment: how would that cut off any leading 0's?

Comment: I think this does not change the gist of what I am trying to illustrate. I am not doing homework, I am giving direction. :) I think you could adapt it reasonably starting from there.

Comment: A more portable method (and doesn't rely on Endianness), is to isolate the least significant byte:  `uint8_t byte = (uint8_t)(toWrite & 0xFFU); out.write(&byte, 1);`

Comment: It could be a good solution if toWrite is smaller than 1 byte. But it is not general.